# Windows 7 .NET 3.5.1 - 2.0 Slightly Corrupted, How to Repair?

Tags: windows, windows-7, .net, .net-3.5

My Windows 7 included .NET installation (3.5 to 2.0) appears very slightly and particularly corrupted and I am trying to fix it without reinstalling Windows or trying to revert to backups.

Everything was working and then my hard drive started corrupting a few files and checkdisk found bad clusters so I imaged the drive to a new one.  As soon as I booted on  the new drive everything worked *except* programs which call the System.Net.NetworkInformation methods within .NET 3.5 to 2.0 (like Ping() and IsNetworkAvailable()), which immediately crash the app in which the calls are (those calls in .NET 4.0 works fine). Those methods are found inside System.dll, and I assume call native methods which I believe are inside winnsi.dll or iphlpapi.dll or something else (I've not found this yet); I assume it calls native methods because the exception which causes the crash is Fatal Execution Engine Error which people mention is usually related to calling native methods and marshaling data between them.

A huge clue about the culprit is likely found in the fact that when I launch the exact same crashing application through a code profiler (which executes the exe and captures stats on which methods took the longest) the app works fine, no crash at all!  How could running it within the profiler work and running it outside not work?  That seems the key to the mystery.

- I've used procmon to catch all the registry, filesystem, and network events from the crashing execution and the profiler-run successful execution and compared the two outputs but didn't learn much (I see the moment at which the non-profiled app crashes, but up until then they behave the same, loaded the same modules, ).  The only big difference seems to be that at the moment before the app crash the profiler-executed code creates 4-6 new threads and the directly executed code only creates 1-2.
- I have diffed the files/directories which seemed most relevant (the .NET stuff under Windows and Program Files) pre- and post- disk trouble and seen no changes where I didn't expect any (no obvious file corruption).
- I have diffed the software and system registry hives pre- and post- disk trouble and seen no changes which seemed relevant.
- I have created a new user account and cleaned up any environment variables in case environment was related.  No change.
- I did "sfc /scannow" and it found no integrity problems.
- I tried "ngen update" to regenerate pre-compiled code in case I missed something that might be damaged and nothing changed.

I assume I need to repair my .NET installation but because Windows 7 included .NET 3.5 - 2.0 you can't just re-run a .NET installer to redo it.  I do not have access to the Windows disks to try to re-install Windows over itself (the computer has a recovery partition but it is unusable); also the drive uses a whole-disk encryption solution and re-installing would be difficult.

I absolutely do not want to start from scratch here and install a fresh Windows, reinstall dozens of software packages, try and remember dozens of development-related customizations/etc.

Given all that...  does anyone have any helpful advice?  I need .NET 3.5 - 2.0 working as I am a developer and need to build and test against it.

Thanks!

Quinxy

Comment: have you seen this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx

Comment: Thanks for sharing that.  Sadly I did look at that and some of the other great .NET related stuff on that site, and I didn't find anything which related to my situation of trying to uninstall, repair, or re-install an OS-included .NET version.  The tool you link to and the others on that site and even the AiO Runtime bundle I found elsewhere all refuse to touch OS-included .NET runtimes.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that my System.ni.dll file was damaged, I replaced it and all is well.

I remembered that I should recheck the chkdsk log I kept listing the files that were damaged by the drive failure.  After the failure I had turned all the listed file ids into file paths/names and I had replaced all the 100+ files I could from backup but sure enough when I went back now and looked I found a note that while I had replaced 4 or 5 .NET related files successfully there was one such file I wasn't able to replace because it was "in use" at the time.  That file?  System.ni.dll!!!  I was now able to replace this file from backup and voila my .NET install is back to normal, apps work whether profiled or not.

The frustrating thing is that when this incident first occurred I fully expected the problem to relate to a damaged file, and specifically to a file called System.dll which housed the methods that failed.  And so I diffed and rediffed all files named System.dll.  But I did not realize at that time that System.ni.dll was a native compiled manifestation of System.dll (or somesuch).  And because I had diffed and rediffed the .NET related directories and not noticed this (no idea how I missed it) I'd given up on that approach.

Anyway...  long story short, it was a damaged System.ni.dll that caused my problems, one or more clusters within it had their content replaced with 0x0 and it just so happened to manifest as the odd problem I observed.